# Lower level syslogs not sending

Tags: logging, syslog

We have an MPLS router (ISR4351) in our main data center that reboot itself, causing it and connections to ISR's at other sites to go down. We export our syslogs to a server, and for some reason, none of the ISR's sent any syslogs about connections coming back up or other information concerning the reboot, even though they all send informational syslogs fine.

Here's what we have for our logging config:

```
DC_MPLS#sh run | i log
logging userinfo
logging buffered 32000
no logging console
log config
  logging enable
  logging size 200
  notify syslog contenttype plaintext
ip ssh logging events
logging origin-id ip
logging facility syslog
logging source-interface Loopback0
logging host 10.10.101.68 transport udp port 1514
logging host 10.10.101.14
logging synchronous
```

Comment: Where are you setting the logging level?

Comment: it's set to debugging

Comment: The routers have access to the syslog server when the MPLS router goes down?

Comment: Some do, we have a P2P connection to some of our sites from the DC.

Comment: The default is info (6) - which is what your snipet would suggest. But that's not the problem. You won't see anything if the route to the syslog server isn't available at the time the message is generated.

Comment: It might be helpful to connect a terminal or KVM to the USB console port and log all output there - on a system crash, that's where a panic message might come up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of syslog messages you are expecting to see.  But here are a few things to keep in mind.  These are general statements, and there are exceptions and special situations for each of these items.

1. On the branch routers, you can do a `show logg` to see what messages were issued.  If you don't see a message in the RAM, then there is no reason to expect that the branch router even attempted to send a copy to the syslog server.  (The levels can be set differently if you want them to be.)
2. If the syslog server is located in the main data center site, then any syslogs that the branch routers send will be lost when the main router is down.  Since they're UDP, they're lost forever.  (You can have sequence numbers added to messages so that missing logs can be detected.)
3. Routers do not log route changes.  So, if you're running BGP over your MPLS and some prefixes disappear from BGP, there won't be any messages for that.  (Neighbor changes are sometimes logged, depending on the protocol.)
4. There are extremely few cases where loosing link on the HQ router will cause a branch router to loose link.  With MPLS, metro ethernet, point-to-point links, any most others, you are establishing the layer 1 electrical/optical link with the provider.  Your branches will not see link go down when the HQ reboots.  That means the router will never log the interface going down.
5. Depending on what went wrong with the HQ router that caused it to reboot, it may or may not have sent any syslogs to the server talking about the reboot.  In some cases, the router can crash and still manage to send a final syslog message that it crashed.  But most likely, there will be no messages.